# Unity how to Include an executable to be launch from build

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I have a basic .net console app that needs to be launched at runtime from by Unity app. To achieve this, I have the executable in my StreamingAssets folder along with all of its dependencies.

Everything actaully works as expected and I am able to launch the exe fine using `Process.Start(pathToExe)` inside the unity app.

My issue is that Unity throws a bunch of errors because it doesn't like that the console app's build folder folders has duplicate .dll files. For instance, the build of the console app has 3 different runtime folders (winx64, winx86, winarm). Each of these folders has their own instances of .dll files.

The error unity throws is `Multiple plugins with the same name 'libskiasharp' (found at 'Assets/StreamingAssets/VideoCaptureService/runtimes/win-arm64/native/libSkiaSharp.dll' and 'Assets/StreamingAssets/VideoCaptureService/runtimes/win-x86/native/libSkiaSharp.dll'). That means one or more plugins are set to be compatible with Editor. Only one plugin at the time can be used by Editor. UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)`

The error doesn't seem to affect anything, but I would still like to get rid of it if possible.

Edit: It appears normally there is the option to disable editor compile from the inspector for the plugin files. However, this does not appear to be available for plugins placed in the StreamingAssets folder.

Comment: You can exclude them from the editor in the inspector for each. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html

Comment: @RetiredNinja For whatever reason, the inspector options are not available for plugin inside the StreamingAssets folder. Any other folder they are visible.

Comment: Makes sense since StreamingAssets is special. I wonder if you moved them out, set the exclusions, then moved them back if it would stick. It should keep the existing meta file contents.

Comment: @RetiredNinja This appears to be working! Thanks!